# Setup Prometheus Ingress with Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, prometheus-operator

I have deployed helm chart for prometheus-operator and currently all the services are up and running.

I have already a ingress controller at place and it is routing our internal services perfectly.

But now I am creating ingress for Prometheus, Grafana & AlertManager and it is not working as expected.

My Prometheus Ingress YAML -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prom
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-prom-check-prometheus-o-prometheus
          servicePort: 9090
        path: /prometheus
```

[image]

Output is - *404 not found*

[image]

But for Grafana it doesn't give 404 and rather gives Invalo key error -

[image]

Kindly advise on it. I haven't modified values.yaml and directly installed it.

[image]

Comment: Prometheus is not aware of what you are trying to achieve and that's why it's redirecting to unknown destination. As far as I know you have to tell prometheus to accept traffic on the new path. I assume if you change path from /prometheus to / it should work. if you want it on /prometheus you would have to properly configure routePrefix and routePrefix in your values.yaml. Take a look at github issue about that [here](http://elatov.github.io/2020/02/nginx-ingress-with-alertmanager-and-prometheus/) and [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/11471).

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is not aware of what you are trying to achieve and that's why it's redirecting to unknown destination, you get 404 page not found error message because the http request that gets to the target webserver is claiming for the content of `/prometheus` directory instead of `/` from which it is actually served.

As far as I know you have to tell prometheus to accept traffic on the new path. I assume if you change path from `/prometheus` to `/` it should work.

If you want it on /prometheus you would either have to properly configure the prometheus operator chart values, I assume they are externalUrl and routePrefix.

> prometheus.prometheusSpec.externalUrl -> The external URL the Prometheus instances will be available under. This is necessary to generate correct URLs. This is necessary if Prometheus is not served from root of a DNS name.
>
> prometheus.prometheusSpec.routePrefix -> The route prefix Prometheus registers HTTP handlers for. This is useful, if using ExternalURL and a proxy is rewriting HTTP routes of a request, and the actual ExternalURL is still true, but the server serves requests under a different route prefix. For example for use with kubectl proxy. **Default value is /**

There is related [github issue](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/11471) about that

**OR**

Configure your nginx to rewrite from `/prometheus` to `/`.

The following ingress definition should resolve your problem

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-prom-check-prometheus-o-prometheus
          servicePort: 9090
        path: /prometheus(/|$)(.*)
```

Rewrite that was used above will ensure that the original access path /prometheus gets rewritten to / before reaching the target Pod.

There is [tutorial](http://elatov.github.io/2020/02/nginx-ingress-with-alertmanager-and-prometheus/) about that.

Answer (score 0):

If an ingress controller is already in place, prometheus can be accessed on the custom domain by using following values in your values.yaml.

Is there a specific reason you are manually trying to configure and deploy prometheus ingress yourself?

Using following values in your [values.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml) will create a prometheus ingress for you.

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: {kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"}
  labels: {}
  ## Hostnames.
  ## Must be provided if Ingress is enabled.
  ##
  # hosts:
  #   - prometheus.domain.com
  hosts: []
  ## Paths to use for ingress rules - one path should match the prometheusSpec.routePr
  ##
  paths:
    - /
```

Now, you'll be able to access your prometheus UI on localhost via browser.